# 1<2<3 is true but reverse of this 3>2>1 is false, why?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am new in programming and learning web development, when I was doing practice of Boolean data type in javascript I got a problem with this:

Code:
"
console.log(1<2<3);
console.log(3>2>1);
"

Output:
true
false

I know the answer for the first one is true, but for second one why it printed false.

Comment: if you evaluate 2 numbers at a time, you'll get it.

Comment: it is because javascript evaluated as this:

3>2 = true, then javascript tries to convert the values to number, so true will become 1, and so it becomes 1>1 which is false.

that is why console.log(1<2<3) is true because 1 < 2 is true, then javascript converts the true to 1, so 1 < 3 which is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between console.log(1 < 2 < 3); and console.log(3 > 2 > 1); lies in how JavaScript handles the comparison operators.

Let's break down each expression:

console.log(1 < 2 < 3);

In this case, the expression is evaluated from left to right.
1 < 2 is true, so it becomes true < 3.
JavaScript converts true to 1 in a numeric context, so it becomes 1 < 3.
The final result is true.
console.log(3 > 2 > 1);

Similar to the first example, this expression is also evaluated from left to right.
3 > 2 is true, so it becomes true > 1.
JavaScript converts true to 1 in a numeric context, so it becomes 1 > 1.
The final result is false.
The reason for the difference in behavior is that the < and > operators are left-associative in JavaScript, meaning they are evaluated from left to right. So, in the second example, it first evaluates 3 > 2, which is true, and then compares true > 1, which is false.

```
console.log((1 < 2) < 3);  // true
console.log(3 > (2 > 1));  // true
```

Try this

Comment: sure, those `()` make it look like it's working .... but what about `3 > 2 > 3` - should that be true or false? :p lets imagine a piece of code is doing `a > b > c` ... and you use your suggestion `a > (b > c)` ...

Comment: 3 > 2 > 3 here the code will execute first 3 > 2 which is true so instead of 3 > 2 there will be 1 and last part here after the result 1 > 3 is false. so you have to understand what is happening and what will be the precess cause you have to maintain the language low what you are using

Comment: but 3 > 2 > 3 .... is it true or false? my point is, the OP expected 3 > 2 > 1 to be true, but you had to put `()` to make it true. But 3 > 2 > 3 should be false, and `3 > 2 > 3` does produce false, but, adding the brackets, `3 > (2 > 3)` becomes true. My point being, the `()` are not the answer, in general, `a > b > c` should be written `(a > b) && (b > c)`

Answer (score 1):

First, it evaluates "3 > 2," which is true.
Then, it evaluates "true > 1," treating "true" as 1 in a numerical context, which is false.